# maps in shared memory: Boost.Interprocess demo fails due to unmet date_time dependency

Tags: c++, boost, linker, shared-memory, dependency-management

I want to create shared `map` objects that multiple processes can access.  The most promising approach I've found is [this demo code from Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers_of_containers), which allocates `map` objects in a managed shared memory segment.  This question will mostly be about the boost problems I'm having, but I'd also be grateful if anyone has non-boost alternative approaches.

I'm completely new to boost: it looks amazing, if huge, and I was encouraged by its claim that "often, there's nothing to build". But in this case that promise is broken in what seems to be a senseless way, and I'm failing to compile the demo because of dependency problems internal to boost.

I'm on Windows, with Visual C++ Express 2010 installed. After saving the demo code as `shmap.cpp` I do the following:

```
"%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
cl /EHsc /I boost_1_57_0 shmap.cpp
```

It compiles OK, but then I get this:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-s-1_57.lib'
```

This surprises me on a number of levels. **(Q1)**: I didn't ask for libraries---where and how is boost leading the linker to expect them?  **(Q2)**: Why would it be asking for `date_time` in particular?  At no point in the code is anything as functionally specific as a date or time computed, referenced or included.  Is this a case of overzealous blanket dependency, and if so is there a way I can weed it out?

Regardless, the obvious first thing to try was to play the game: in the `boost_1_57_0` directory I ran `bootstrap.bat` followed by `b2`. The Earth turned a good few degrees, boost was built successfully, and I retried with:

```
cl /EHsc /I boost_1_57_0 shmap.cpp /link /LIBPATH:boost_1_57_0\stage\lib
```

I still get the same linker error. This is because `b2` seems to have built libs with `-mt-` and with `-mt-gd-` in their names, but not with the `-mt-s-` that the linker is looking for.  Boost's "Getting Started" webpage tells me what these stand for but doesn't tell me **(Q3)**: how can I change either the type of library that gets built, or the type that the linker expects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "At no point in the code is anything as functionally specific as a date or time computed, referenced or included."
>
> **(Q2)**: Why would it be asking for date_time in particular?

Apparently the things you used depend on it.

E.g the mutex operations have **[`timed_lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes.mutexes_mutex_operations)** function

> **(Q1)**: I didn't add libraries to the project---where and how is boost leading the linker to expect them?

Boost does autolinking by default. This uses MSVC++ specific pragmas to indicate the right flavour of the right link libraries. This is an awesome feature.

You just have to make sure the import libraries are on the library path for your project.

---

There are ways to disable auto-linking in boost (I think it involves defining  BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)

There *might* be ways to

- disable dependency on boost date_time (dropping features); see the **[autl-link description in the Getting Started guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking)**
- linking to date_Time statically (or make it header-only)

I'd refer to the documentation for this.

Comment: Thanks! These insights help a lot, and  `/DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` does indeed let me build my demo. Though if you're right about `timed_lock`, then I guess my problem is just deferred until I start using mutexes.  Looks like I'll need to wade into the boost build doc to figure out how to obtain the "right flavour" of library in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've learned, in large part thanks to [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe):

Q1: It's magic---specifically, MSVC-specific magic---and it happens because it's necessary.

Q2: It becomes *unnecessary*---i.e. the demo can be compiled without needing to look for a binary `date_time` lib---if I add `/DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` to the compile flags. But it's unclear whether that will still be true once I start to use additional IPC functionality like time-dependent mutexing.

Q3: Strings from the "Boost.Build option" column of [this table](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) can be passed to `b2`, so the way to create `*-mt-s-*.lib` is to say `b2 runtime-link=static`. This finally lets me compile without the `/DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` flag, and discover that `date_time` is the only library the demo seems to need.

I also discovered that the dependencies can be tracked with [the bcp tool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html), and (eventually) also how to build `bcp` in the first place, as follows:

```
build:
cd boost_1_57_0
bjam tools\bcp
cd ..

report:
boost_1_57_0\dist\bin\bcp.exe --boost=boost_1_57_0 --report --scan shmap.cpp  report.html
```

The result is that the maps-in-shared-memory demo needs 1421 files from boost 1.57.0.