# Is Visual Studio adding dependencies from out of nowhere?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, windows-7-x64

I'm having a problem building a windows C++ project with a specially modified version of the boost library.  I'm not using bjam, but instead have a custom project using cmake to manage building a small sub-set of the boost libraries.  Everything seems to compile fine, but then I get a linking error for an entity that was never mentioned in cmake or any of the source files:

```
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib'
```

I searched for this string in my build folder using 'findstr', and found it mentioned in thread.obj in this context:

```
/DEFAULTLIB:liboobst_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib
```

My question is: where did this /DEFAULTLIB tag come from and how do I prevent it?  I turned on explicit compile and linking flags ("Suppress Startup Banner"=No) and it is not mentioned anywhere during the build process.

Edit:
Per commenters, this is part of the auto-linking feature in boost, which can be disabled with the BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB definition. Described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254718/maps-in-shared-memory-boost-interprocess-demo-fails-due-to-unmet-date-time-depe/27254899#27254899).

Comment: My guess is, it's from a `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` in the code somewhere.

Comment: It comes from a boost .hpp file, it contains #pragma comment(lib, "...").  You'll need to tell the linker where to look for the .lib file, it can't find it by itself because it doesn't know where you put boost.

Comment: Is there a proper way to tell Boost to not specify those pragma lib statements?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254718/maps-in-shared-memory-boost-interprocess-demo-fails-due-to-unmet-date-time-depe/27254899#27254899

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the commenters, this is part of the auto-linking feature in boost, which can be disabled with the BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB definition. Described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254718/maps-in-shared-memory-boost-interprocess-demo-fails-due-to-unmet-date-time-depe/27254899#27254899).